# Future tenses in

Tags: future-constructions

We can use the future simple to show that one action will happen after another for example "When she comes I will tell her the truth" We can use the future continuous to show that two actions happen at the same time While she's sleeping I will be playing. We are also allowed to use  the future continuous for future arrangments. Now my question is

1 When I retire I will read many books

2 When I retire I will be reading many books

1 is correct shows sequence. What about 2? Can it be right when reading books is our future plan, arrangment and not some spontaneous decision? I think that 2 may have two meanings either that when i'm in the midle of reading I become a senior or second as I stated before that reading books is my plan for the retirement. Is that right?

Comment: Reading depends on retiring, not the other way around. So no: When I'm in the middle of reading I become a senior. And all 3 explanations of the future in your first paragraph are the same: the future. No need for separate rules.

Comment: So both sentences are fine and mean the same thing?

Comment: #1and #2 mean almost the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The question is [moot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moot), because people would generally not say either sentence. Rather, it would be expressions like:

"After I retire, I'm planning to read a lot."
"After I retire, I'm just gonna play golf, and read."

Nevertheless, we can consider your original examples.

What is intended to be communicated? If it's the meaning of sentence 1, then the choice should be sentence 1. The second sentence appears to be awkward, unusual, and somewhat incorrect.

Yes, perhaps you could imagine a scenario "I will probably be out tending the garden, when the tornado comes and destroys the town."
And that is indeed similar to "I will probably be reading, when the hour passes that I actually enter retirement."  However, there are problems with that:

1. You will be reading a book, not "many books", when the moment occurs. So you should remove the "many books" part.
2. This is a funny meaning, and probably not what 99% of people are trying to say. Rather, they intend sentence 1.

The other interpretation you suggested is "as I stated before that reading books is my plan for the retirement."  For that, I think it's not the best choice. The selection between "future simple" and "future continuous" is governed by many rules. [How to Use the Future Continuous Tense](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/future-continuous-tense/) covers the topic in some detail.

One way to think about it, is that the "simple future tense" is the default choice. You should prefer the "future simple" unless you have a specific reason to switch to "future continuous". For example "You will be doing X, when Y happens".  That shows the events overlap. So it's a valid reason.  Is your "reading many books" overlapping with something?  No, because really you mean "*after* you retire", not "*when* you retire".  And, reading (over many years) is not one event in time.

Nevertheless, it's a tricky topic. By rephrasing the sentence, you could probably find some ways to convert it to "future continuous".

Comment: Thank you. One more question. In the past we wouldn't say "Last week I was fixing my car" unless we add something like "for hours, when I decided to quit or while she was cooking at home" without that past simple is right. I can see that future continuous works differently we could say "I will be fixing my car next week" without adding anything more. I think it is because we are allowed to use future continuous like present continuous for future arrangment. Therefore, could it be natural to say "What will you be doing tomorrow or in a week even if we don't mean any particular moment

Comment: During tomorrow. I mean when it comes to the past we use past continuous for some particular moment. We don't just say " What were you doing yesterday" alone without "all day or when I called or while I was having fun". I understand why then saying "last week I was fixing my car" on its own is incorrect. It would be strange to be allowed to say "I will be fixing my car next week" on its own but not okay and natural to use " What will you be doing tomorrow" even if we don't mean any particular time during tomorrow

Comment: Yes, "What will you be doing tomorrow" is a valid option, among various. By the way,  the "many books" adds complexity to the original question.   If you remove "many books", and only consider "I'll be reading (a lot)", it's a step closer to sounding correct.  Actually, the more I repeat the sentences to myself, over and over, they fade into meaninglessness, and I can't tell the difference anymore.  :-)

Comment: Thank you so much just to be sure. You state that " What will you be doing tomorrow" is fine and nautal even if we don't think about any specific time during " tomorrow" ? Unlike " what were you doing yesterday" which without some specific time is wrong? Am I right?

Comment: Usually you would say "what were you doing yesterday, after lunch". There would be more substance in the sentence.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Nevertheless in let's say more formal language there is a difference between "what did you do yesterday" and :what we were doing yesterday". :What did you do yesterday" is more like a summary of things which you did and "what we were doing yesterday" on average asks about some particular time for example what we're doing yesterday while  I was having fun with friends. My question is what about "what will you do tomorrow" and "what will you be doing tomorrow" As I said before it is okay to say "I will be fixing my car next week "without any additional

Comment: information. Therefore, i'd like to know if it's okay to say what will you be doing tomorrow without any specific specific time

Comment: "what are you doing tomorrow" is a conversational way of making plans with someone. Otherwise, in other circumstances, when using the future tense, you'd specify more info. "what will you be doing tomorrow, when the space shuttle is scheduled to launch?" As I mentioned before, there are other ways to express the future tense besides "will" which are often preferable.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you explain then why it is okay to say "I will be fixing my car next week" without any additonal activity or specific time?